# Approval Button on Email Body?

Tags: email, workflow

I'm using SharePoint 2007, developed a form library. The form needs an approval after it's created.
One form has more than one approver, its working sequentially on workflow. Every approver will get a notification email.

I'm wandering if it is possible to put the approval button on email body?
So the approver could response directly on his/her email without open the form on browser.
Or is there any other solutions that can help me to deliver this problem of mine?

Answer (score 2):

A workflow product called [Nintex](http://nintex.com) Workflow offers a functionality similar to what you want.  Their proprietary feature is called LazyApproval.  When enabled, an email is sent to the task approver.

The user simply has to reply with Approve or Reject or any other defined keywords to give the approval and the workflow carries on.

Answer (score 1):

You can only call URLs from an e-mail, so only if you create your own workflow which accepts `GET` Parameters you could achieve approving via E-Mail.

Then you could call an URL like `http://mysite/Lists/MyList/Workflow?ApproveBoss=true` and would have to check whether it's really the person which is approving.
In SharePoint 2010 together with Office 2010, InfoPath Forms can be **directly opened** from within Office Applications so you can *directly approve* stuff.

Maybe that's a reason for your boss to upgrade to SharePoint 2010. In the end the standard link to a task form isn't that ugly, is it? The use clicks on the link "Click here to approve", Internet Explorer opens with the task, the user can enter comments and click "Approve". That's the standard way.

Comment: i already have a button that can approve or reject on my form,
is there anyway i could get the link on the button so i can put it on my mail body?

thanks for help.